# I went from bottling to refridge

Tags: carbonation, stuck-fermentation

I bottled then right to refrigerator. What can I expect? Been in the fridge for about 2weeks.Is the Beer lost?Can I remove it now or is it to late?

Comment: You primed your bottles with sugar?  What type of yeast did you use?

Comment: Used suger cubes, believe either Ale or regular brewing yeast

Comment: I usually use granulated sugar to carbonate. Haven't had any issues yet. And it's A-Affordable process.

Comment: It happened to me once because of a messed up thermostat. Just pulled the beer out, let it rest over night in ambient temperature. The other day I gently shook it and placed it OUT of the fridge. One week later it was carbonated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cold in the fridge shouldn't kill the yeast, but it will slow it down. So if you generally bottle condition for two weeks, it most likely won't be ready after two weeks in the fridge. I suggest taking it out of the fridge for a week and testing it then.

Personally, I like keeping my beer out at room temperature even after it is ready because I like it aged a bit. I only put like 4 beers in the fridge at once (unless I'm like having a party) so I have cold beer but let the rest age.

Comment: Avi thank you very much very helpful information.

Answer (score 3):

It is not too late. In fact the bottles will condition/carbonate in a fridge (5°C) quite well but will take somewhat longer to do so.

Try taking the bottles out of the refrigerator and leaving them for (say) two weeks in a warm (room temperature/20°C) place. One can shake the bottles to disperse any settled yeast if one wishes to. That should rouse the yeast from any slumber and allow bottle conditioning to proceed at full speed. After that time the bottles can still be left out of the fridge to age.

I personally recommend bottle conditioning/ageing for at last a month if not more. Obviously, the bottles can be returned to the fridge before drinking!

Comment: Took Beer out of fridge the night of the 7th of July. Just returned to the fridge this morning. Will keep in fridge until next Tuesday. Will let all know the results. Thanks for all the input and advice from everyone.

Comment: Was 5 days enough to carbonate the beer? How did it go?

Comment: It came out good.

Comment: Pete, got a question, what is the easiest way to raise the A.B.V on my home brews.

Comment: There are some caveats - but generally adding fermentable sugars (eg maltose/sucrose/dextrose but not lactose) to a wort will increase the final  ABV. On the other hand a cynic might say the easiest way is to pour in a bottle of vodka!

Comment: Pete: Thanks I am was thinking about the same. Adding more sugers , would the best practice be to add during the wort or after i pitch the yeast or does it make a difference?

Comment: It might be best to add the sugars to the wort just before finishing the boil. Then the sugar would be sterilised as well as the rest of the ingredients. Alternatively you could dissolve it in a minimum of boiled water and add to the wort in the fermenting vessel. It is usually better to add it before the yeast - then the fermenting vessel can be sealed and not re-opened until completion of fermentation.

Comment: Thanks Pete that helps a lot. Everything is more understandable now.